# How to retrieve a value from a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to make a *vector* that **contains** vectors, that contains a *string*. I am unsure on how I would go about retrieving said string. I've tried **vector.at()** but I'm not sure how to make a sort of *'multi-layered'* version of it.

This is the value inside of my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> dialoguestore;
```

Comment: `vector.at` gives you another vector, so call `at` on it again.

Comment: What about repeatedly applying the `[]` indexing operator: `std::string s = dialoguestore[0][0];`

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this with a 2D vector.

**Option 1: `at()`:**

```
dialoguestore.at(index).at(index2);
```

**Option 2: `operator[]:`**

```
dialoguestore[index][index2]
```

If you have a multidimensional vector, use the ways you normally access a vector, but for the number of dimensions.